# Extend Javascript Library which don't have typescript defination in Typescript-Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

Please let me know whether I’m following correct approach or not. If not please suggest me correct approach.

I using some javascript library in Typescript(Angular 4). I've snippet of javascript function:

```
(function(Handsontable){
  var CustomEditor = Handsontable.editors.BaseEditor.prototype.extend();

  // ...rest of the editor code

  // Put editor in dedicated namespace
  Handsontable.editors.CustomEditor = CustomEditor;

  // Register alias
  Handsontable.editors.registerEditor('theBestEditor', CustomEditor);

})(Handsontable);
```

I’ve extend this library in typescript file of Angular like this:

```
declare var Handsontable : any;
constructor (
const autocompleteEditor2 = Handsontable.editors.AutocompleteEditor.prototype.extend();
Handsontable.editors.autocompleteEditor2 = autocompleteEditor2;
Handsontable.editors.registerEditor('autocompleteEditor2', autocompleteEditor2);
)
```

Answer (score 0):

[`npm install --save-dev @types/Handsontable`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/handsontable) and provide it into your `tsconfig.json`

Further Info Here: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/tsconfig-json.html#types-typeroots-and-types

Comment: I don't want to use @types/Handsontable rather I'll "declare var Handsontable : any;" and I'll extend it's prototype. It's kind of IIFEs - Immediately Invoked Function Expressions in Angular 4 using Typescript. Please help me on this regard.

Comment: If you don't want to download ambient declaration for that, then, don't do it. Handcrafted ambient declarations are completely pointless and doing `var foo:any` doesn't add any value, it just ignores compiler warnings. The only way is to download ambient declaration for that library and you should do it because this is one of the most powerful features of TS.

Comment: problem we have is we are using *declare var foo:any* for long time. Now project is in prod. But we got specific request to customize *foo*. So we are not in a position to so this. That's the reason I'm asking for is there any way to customize *foo* in the form of *javascript prototype* kind of extension in *typescript*

Comment: once you declare some `var` as `any` value, then you can do whatever you want with it, typescript won't complain at all. so, just basically write your program just after that ambient declaration...

Comment: I implemented similar way but I'm wondering what will be the right way. Looking for Angular-Typesript expert to answer this.

Comment: interface Process {
    exit(code?: number): void;
}
declare var process: Process;
interface Process {
    exitWithLogging(code?: number): void;
}
process.exitWithLogging = function() {
    console.log("exiting");
    process.exit.apply(process, arguments);
};